# I want to count the number of alphabets using a dictionary function and sort

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, input, key

Example:

```
Enter DNA : ACRSAS

A=2

C=1

R=2

S=2
```

I want to make this function like example with dictionary and sorting.

```
sequence=input("Enter DNA: ")

sequence_1=sequence.upper

sequence_list=list(sequence_1)
```

I've written the function so far.

How can I print an example like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work...

```
from collections import Counter
sequence=input("Enter DNA: ")
sequence_1=sequence.upper()
sequence_list= list(sequence_1)
print(Counter(sequence_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired result:

```
for element in sorted(set(sequence_1))
    print(element +"=" + str(sequence_1.count(element)))
```